# Iterating over multiple columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 1), index=dates, columns='price')
for x in range(10):

    df[str(x)]=df['price'].rolling.mean(x)
```

I want to calculate the difference between two columns x and y where x is greater than y.

For example:

```
df[str(2)-str(1)]=np.diff(df['2']-df['1'])
```

Similarly (3-1),(4-1)....(9-1)
And (3-2).....(9-2)
And(4-3)....(9-3)
So on

(10-9).

How to do this using for loop or apply method?
Please suggest the way forward. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is going to be a lot of columns...

Comment: Yes sir. I want them.